# Clion IDE comments my second part of code. What can I do?

Tags: c, comments, clion

Hi I am writing some code for finite automata but that is not important.

When I try to write in CLion my second part of the code is commented (from line 32 case JEDNORADKOVA). Do you know how can I repair my CLion or where is problem then?

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


typedef enum {START ,POSSIBLE_COMMENT, SINGLE_LINECOMMENT, MULTILINECOMMENT,MULTILINECOMMENT_MAYBE_END, QUOTATION_MARKS} tStates;

int main() {
  tStates state = START;
    printf("Delete of comments. Enter input \n");
    int sighn ;

    while((sighn=getchar())  != EOF)
    {
        switch (state) {
            case START:
                if (sighn == '/') {
                  state = POSSIBLE_COMMENT; }
                else{
                    putchar(sighn);
                }



            case SINGLE_LINECOMMENT:
                if (sighn == '\n')
                    state=  START;

                case MULTILINECOMMENT:
                 if (sighn == '*')

                break;



            case MULTILINECOMMENT_MAYBE_END:


            case QUOTATION_MARKS:


                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

MY code in CLion

[image: MY code in CLion]

My code in VS Code

[image: My code in VS Code]

Comment: What do you mean by "the code is commented"?

Comment: @Barmar My code is greyed out just like comments. But I dont see there any commeents so I dont know why it is behaving like comment when there is no `/` I run it in VS code but it ran just fine. It only comments it in my CLion and I don't know why.

Comment: `else putchar('/');` is the only code that is attached to the `else`. The code in the braces below that will always be executed. That formatting may be confusing the IDE. `if (znak = '*')` is missing an `=`, so the value will be assigned, not compared.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes I tried to put `=` in `if (znak = '*')` but the rest of the code is still behaving like commented.

Comment: I copied your code into CLion and it didn't do this. It highlights the bad test `if (znak = '*')` but everything else is normal.

Comment: @Barmar So maybe I try to run it in new window to see if I will have same result like you do. I also repair that part by adding `=` into that expression so it looks like `if (znak =='*')`

Comment: @Barmar So I opened it in new window but I still have problem. Maybe I can try post here a screen shot but I am afraid it is not allowed here.

Comment: @Barmar I posted there two screenshots from CLion and VS Code so you can see what I ment.

Comment: I don't see any grey there.

Comment: @Barmar Hi I added screen shots from CLion and VS Code there so look at the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the messages in CLion: "*Unreachable code :32*" and the error is clear.

I have formatted your source, but it seems to be not the one you have in CLion. Since the indenting and bracing are chaotic, I assume that you have a closing brace too much.

Comment: it is same code.

Comment: Maybe I can ask JetBrains developers themselves about this problem. :)

Comment: Can you reduce the source without losing the effect? If so, do this until you cannot remove more, and then add the resulting source to your question.

Comment: So I reduced the code.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
case MOZNA_POZNAMKA:
            if (znak == '/')
                stav = JEDNORADKOVA;
            else
                putchar('/');
                
            putchar(znak);
            stav = START;
            break;
```

regardless of the value in `znak`, this will print one or two '/' characters then set the next 'switch' selector to `START`  probably not what you want as it results in the next couple of `cases` never being executed

Comment: What this code should do is basicly mealey finite automata it is when you type for example `hello / world` it will only print `hello` that is purpose of this whole code.

Comment: @Leviathan,  the OP wanted to know why the last few switch cases were not being executed.  That is the question I answered

Comment: I know I asked that question man I am OP :D